# Directus Repeater Field does not trigger filter hook

Tags: javascript, hook, directus, headless-cms

Using Directus version 9.8, I have created a Repeater Field with two option ( title, description ).

[image]

I have added data in those repeater field.

[image]

I have created the following hook and this hook is getting triggered when i add data to repeater field, but when i update the value of existing Repeater field, then the Hook is not getting triggered.

```
import { defineHook } from '@directus/extensions-sdk';

export default defineHook(({ filter, action }) => {
    filter('items.create', (input, { collection }, { schema }) => {
        console.log('Creating Item!', input, collection, schema);
    });
    filter('items.update', (input, { collection }, { schema }) => {
        console.log('Updating Item!', input, collection, schema);
    });  
});
```

Generally Filter hook is triggered for updation operation in normal Fields. But
the issue is the filter hook is not getting triggered for updation operation for repeater field. so the console log "Updating Item" is not getting logged in to console.
Please help me to fix this issue or share your thoughts.

Comment: Were you able to customize the display of repeater fields in the UI, like showing both the title and description? In my case, the title is only displayed, and to check description each time, I need to click on the title, and then it draws a right sidebar where I can see the description. I want to see both the title and desc in the UI where field entries are shown.

Comment: @Gaurav there is an option while creating the repeater field. You can use Interface => Template => {{title}} {{description}}. If you can create a separate question and add the link here, i will share the screenshot over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i update to the latest version (9.10) of the Directus, then it was working fine.